# Convert guides to vector objects

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I'm making an identity book, and I'd like to show proportions used in the logo construction. The effect is easly achieved by using guidelines - **can i convert guidelines to vector objects** (I'd like to save this "construction" as vector).

Or even better - create stripped lines on top of grid guides?

Comment: Select guide(s) and `View > Guides > Release guides`

Comment: I think you can post this as the answer. No need to write a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, according to [this post](https://openstudioblog.wordpress.com/2009/07/16/illustrator-tip-convert-guides-to-paths-for-printing/) by Open Studio creating paths from guides can be done this way.

> Create a path from a guide so it can be printed or manipulated as a
>   vector. Unlock your guides then:
>
> Windows = Hold down Shift + Ctrl + Alt and double click the guide
>
> Mac OS = Hold down Shift + Command + Option and double click the guide

[image]

I've tried this with AI CS6 and it works fine, however with regular guides there is an extra step. The new line extends the full length of the art board and can be cumbersome! While selected, type the dimension of the width of the document (or whatever measurement you'd like) in the control panel and now your guide is a line that fits on the page!

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know what "Shift Control Alt Double-click" does... but it worked?